# live output from subprocess command

Tags: python, shell, logging, error-handling, subprocess

I'm using a python script as a driver for a hydrodynamics code.  When it comes time to run the simulation, I use `subprocess.Popen` to run the code, collect the output from `stdout` and `stderr` into a `subprocess.PIPE` --- then I can print (and save to a log-file) the output information, and check for any errors.  The problem is, I have no idea how the code is progressing. If I run it directly from the command line, it gives me output about what iteration its at, what time, what the next time-step is, etc.

**Is there a way to both store the output (for logging and error checking), and also produce a live-streaming output?**

The relevant section of my code:

```
ret_val = subprocess.Popen( run_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True )
output, errors = ret_val.communicate()
log_file.write(output)
print output
if( ret_val.returncode ):
    print "RUN failed\n\n%s\n\n" % (errors)
    success = False

if( errors ): log_file.write("\n\n%s\n\n" % errors)
```

Originally I was piping the `run_command` through `tee` so that a copy went directly to the log-file, and the stream still output directly to the terminal -- but that way I can't store any errors (to my knowlege).

---

My temporary solution so far:

```
ret_val = subprocess.Popen( run_command, stdout=log_file, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True )
while not ret_val.poll():
    log_file.flush()
```

then, in another terminal, run `tail -f log.txt` (s.t. `log_file = 'log.txt'`).

Comment: Maybe you can use `Popen.poll` as in [a previous Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996887/how-to-replicate-tee-behavior-in-python-when-using-subprocess).

Comment: Some commands that show progress indication (e.g., `git`) do so only if their output is a "tty device" (tested via libc `isatty()`).  In that case you may have to open a pseudo-tty.

Comment: @torek what's a (pseudo-)tty?

Comment: Devices on Unix-like systems that allow a process to pretend to be a user on a serial port.  This is how ssh (server side) works, for instance.  See [python pty library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pty.html), and also [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect).

Comment: Re temporary solution: there's no need to call `flush`, and there *is* need to read from the stderr pipe if the subprocess produces much stderr output.  There is not room enough in a comment field to explain this...

Comment: `while not ret_val.poll()` will create an infinite loop if the process exits successfully, that is if the return value is `0`

Comment: `while not ret_val.poll(): log_file.flush()` is useless (`log_file.flush()` in the parent has no effect on the file buffer in the child), harmful (it is an infinite loop if `ret_val` exits successfully (zero returncode)) and it is not enough (it doesn't read `ret_val.stderr`)

Comment: related: [Python subprocess get children's output to file and terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4984428/4279)

Answer (score 243, accepted):

TLDR for Python 3:

```py
import subprocess
import sys

with open("test.log", "wb") as f:
    process = subprocess.Popen(your_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for c in iter(lambda: process.stdout.read(1), b""):
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(c)
        f.buffer.write(c)
```

---

You have two ways of doing this, either by creating an iterator from the `read` or `readline` functions and do:

```py
import subprocess
import sys

# replace "w" with "wb" for Python 3
with open("test.log", "w") as f:
    process = subprocess.Popen(your_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    # replace "" with b'' for Python 3
    for c in iter(lambda: process.stdout.read(1), ""):
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        f.write(c)
```

or

```py
import subprocess
import sys

# replace "w" with "wb" for Python 3
with open("test.log", "w") as f:
    process = subprocess.Popen(your_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    # replace "" with b"" for Python 3
    for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ""):
        sys.stdout.write(line)
        f.write(line)
```

Or you can create a `reader` and a `writer` file. Pass the `writer` to the [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) and read from the `reader`

```py
import io
import time
import subprocess
import sys

filename = "test.log"
with io.open(filename, "wb") as writer, io.open(filename, "rb", 1) as reader:
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=writer)
    while process.poll() is None:
        sys.stdout.write(reader.read())
        time.sleep(0.5)
    # Read the remaining
    sys.stdout.write(reader.read())
```

This way you will have the data written in the `test.log` as well as on the standard output.

The only advantage of the file approach is that your code doesn't block. So you can do whatever you want in the meantime and read whenever you want from the `reader` in a non-blocking way. When you use `PIPE`, `read` and `readline` functions will block until either one character is written to the pipe or a line is written to the pipe respectively.

Comment: Ugh :-) write to a file, read from it, and sleep in the loop?  There's also a chance the process will end before you've finished reading the file.

Comment: With Python 3, you need `iter(process.stdout.readline, b'')` (i.e. the sentinel passed to [iter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) needs to be a binary string, since `b'' != ''`.

Comment: I also had to use line.decode(sys.stdout.encoding) (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689365/python-3-typeerror-must-be-str-not-bytes-with-sys-stdout-write)

Comment: For binary streams, do this:`for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''): 
   sys.stdout.buffer.write(line)`

Comment: Adding to @JohnMellor 's answer, in Python 3 the following modifications were needed:

`process = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b'')     sys.stdout.write(line.decode(sys.stdout.encoding))
`

Comment: @bergercookie: I think the better adaptation for Python3 is to open the file in binary mode ('wb' instead of 'w'). I added a hint as a comment in the answer.

Comment: but the output is not live, is it? in my experience, it just waits until the process finishes executing and only then prints to the console. Link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026045/how-to-read-live-output-from-subprocess-python-2-7-and-apache

Comment: I used code snippet 1 and 2, but it is not working perfectly. My output is always a bunch of lines together and not a live output. 
I am starting a build process which consumes 100% of my CPU power. Maybe this is an issue. Has anyone an idea how I can get an live output line by line?

Comment: @Dave The problem could be that the process is buffering the standard output and flushes it after a couple of lines. If that's the case there is no way to get a live output. Also you can see a much more complex implementation with file readers and writers here: https://github.com/alefnula/tea/blob/develop/tea/process/process.py

Comment: I ended up here when generically looking for ways to get "live output from a python subprocess". In my situation my subprocess was another python application and it was buffering its output preventing this solution from working for me. If I call the application with "python3 -u" then I am able to get the live output I want.

Hopefully this will help someone else who ends up here.

If your subprocess is not a python application you can try searching for something along the lines "run [whatever] without output buffering" and see if that helps you out.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez You need to change `line` to `line.decode('utf-8')` per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689365/python-3-typeerror-must-be-str-not-bytes-with-sys-stdout-write

Comment: It would be nice to include a bit more on what you are actually doing. Where is the log file created or is it just internal? If it is created on the hard disk how is it ensured that the log file does not get corrupted by a different (parallel running) process using the same principle?

Comment: I am getting`AttributeError: '_io.BufferedWriter' object has no attribute 'buffer'`, any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: In case the derived code enters an infinite loop, check if [`text=True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess.stdout) is set (probably inside [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)), in which case observe whether "`replace '' with b'' for Python 3`" prohibits the iterator from exhausting as intended. I hope this helps someone avoid a sleepless night.

Comment: this does not work

Comment: I get some problem here where it looks like the subproceess has trouble flushing its output consistently, even though we are calling sys.stdout.flush()

Comment: None of these solutions answer the question of having the output live.

Answer (score 120):

### Executive Summary (or "tl;dr" version): it's easy when there's at most one `subprocess.PIPE`, otherwise it's hard.

It may be time to explain a bit about how `subprocess.Popen` does its thing.

(Caveat: this is for Python 2.x, although 3.x is similar; and I'm quite fuzzy on the Windows variant.  I understand the POSIX stuff much better.)

The `Popen` function needs to deal with zero-to-three I/O streams, somewhat simultaneously.  These are denoted `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` as usual.

You can provide:

- `None`, indicating that you don't want to redirect the stream.  It will inherit these as usual instead.  Note that on POSIX systems, at least, this does not mean it will use Python's `sys.stdout`, just Python's *actual* stdout; see demo at end.
- An `int` value.  This is a "raw" file descriptor (in POSIX at least).  (Side note: `PIPE` and `STDOUT` are actually `int`s internally, but are "impossible" descriptors, -1 and -2.)
- A stream—really, any object with a `fileno` method.  `Popen` will find the descriptor for that stream, using `stream.fileno()`, and then proceed as for an `int` value.
- `subprocess.PIPE`, indicating that Python should create a pipe.
- `subprocess.STDOUT` (for `stderr` only): tell Python to use the same descriptor as for `stdout`.  This only makes sense if you provided a (non-`None`) value for `stdout`, and even then, it is only *needed* if you set `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`.  (Otherwise you can just provide the same argument you provided for `stdout`, e.g., `Popen(..., stdout=stream, stderr=stream)`.)

#### The easiest cases (no pipes)

If you redirect nothing (leave all three as the default `None` value or supply explicit `None`), `Pipe` has it quite easy.  It just needs to spin off the subprocess and let it run.  Or, if you redirect to a non-`PIPE`—an `int` or a stream's `fileno()`—it's still easy, as the OS does all the work.  Python just needs to spin off the subprocess, connecting its stdin, stdout, and/or stderr to the provided file descriptors.

#### The still-easy case: one pipe

If you redirect only one stream, `Pipe` still has things pretty easy.  Let's pick one stream at a time and watch.

Suppose you want to supply some `stdin`, but let `stdout` and `stderr` go un-redirected, or go to a file descriptor.  As the parent process, your Python program simply needs to use `write()` to send data down the pipe.  You can do this yourself, e.g.:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write('here, have some data\n') # etc
```

or you can pass the stdin data to `proc.communicate()`, which then does the `stdin.write` shown above.  There is no output coming back so `communicate()` has only one other real job: it also closes the pipe for you.  (If you don't call `proc.communicate()` you must call `proc.stdin.close()` to close the pipe, so that the subprocess knows there is no more data coming through.)

Suppose you want to capture `stdout` but leave `stdin` and `stderr` alone.  Again, it's easy: just call `proc.stdout.read()` (or equivalent) until there is no more output.  Since `proc.stdout()` is a normal Python I/O stream you can use all the normal constructs on it, like:

```
for line in proc.stdout:
```

or, again, you can use `proc.communicate()`, which simply does the `read()` for you.

If you want to capture only `stderr`, it works the same as with `stdout`.

There's one more trick before things get hard.  Suppose you want to capture `stdout`, and also capture `stderr` but *on the same pipe as stdout:*

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

In this case, `subprocess` "cheats"!  Well, it has to do this, so it's not really cheating: it starts the subprocess with both its stdout and its stderr directed into the (single) pipe-descriptor that feeds back to its parent (Python) process.  On the parent side, there's again only a single pipe-descriptor for reading the output.  All the "stderr" output shows up in `proc.stdout`, and if you call `proc.communicate()`, the stderr result (second value in the tuple) will be `None`, not a string.

#### The hard cases: two or more pipes

The problems all come about when you want to use at least two pipes.  In fact, the `subprocess` code itself has this bit:

```
def communicate(self, input=None):
    ...
    # Optimization: If we are only using one pipe, or no pipe at
    # all, using select() or threads is unnecessary.
    if [self.stdin, self.stdout, self.stderr].count(None) >= 2:
```

But, alas, here we've made at least two, and maybe three, different pipes, so the `count(None)` returns either 1 or 0.  We must do things the hard way.

On Windows, this uses `threading.Thread` to accumulate results for `self.stdout` and `self.stderr`, and has the parent thread deliver `self.stdin` input data (and then close the pipe).

On POSIX, this uses `poll` if available, otherwise `select`, to accumulate output and deliver stdin input.  All this runs in the (single) parent process/thread.

Threads or poll/select are needed here to avoid deadlock.  Suppose, for instance, that we've redirected all three streams to three separate pipes.  Suppose further that there's a small limit on how much data can be stuffed into to a pipe before the writing process is suspended, waiting for the reading process to "clean out" the pipe from the other end.  Let's set that small limit to a single byte, just for illustration.  (This is in fact how things work, except that the limit is much bigger than one byte.)

If the parent (Python) process tries to write several bytes—say, `'go\n'`to `proc.stdin`, the first byte goes in and then the second causes the Python process to suspend, waiting for the subprocess to read the first byte, emptying the pipe.

Meanwhile, suppose the subprocess decides to print a friendly "Hello! Don't Panic!" greeting.  The `H` goes into its stdout pipe, but the `e` causes it to suspend, waiting for its parent to read that `H`, emptying the stdout pipe.

Now we're stuck: the Python process is asleep, waiting to finish saying "go", and the subprocess is also asleep, waiting to finish saying "Hello! Don't Panic!".

The `subprocess.Popen` code avoids this problem with threading-or-select/poll.  When bytes can go over the pipes, they go.  When they can't, only a thread (not the whole process) has to sleep—or, in the case of select/poll, the Python process waits simultaneously for "can write" or "data available", writes to the process's stdin only when there is room, and reads its stdout and/or stderr only when data are ready.  The `proc.communicate()` code (actually `_communicate` where the hairy cases are handled) returns once all stdin data (if any) have been sent and all stdout and/or stderr data have been accumulated.

If you want to read both `stdout` and `stderr` on two different pipes (regardless of any `stdin` redirection), you will need to avoid deadlock too.  The deadlock scenario here is different—it occurs when the subprocess writes something long to `stderr` while you're pulling data from `stdout`, or vice versa—but it's still there.

---

#### The Demo

I promised to demonstrate that, un-redirected, Python `subprocess`es write to the underlying stdout, not `sys.stdout`.  So, here is some code:

```py
from cStringIO import StringIO
import os
import subprocess
import sys

def show1():
   print 'start show1'
   save = sys.stdout
   sys.stdout = StringIO()
   print 'sys.stdout being buffered'
   proc = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'hello'])
   proc.wait()
   in_stdout = sys.stdout.getvalue()
   sys.stdout = save
   print 'in buffer:', in_stdout

def show2():
   print 'start show2'
   save = sys.stdout
   sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
   print 'after redirect sys.stdout'
   proc = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'hello'])
   proc.wait()
   sys.stdout = save

show1()
show2()
```

When run:

```
$ python out.py
start show1
hello
in buffer: sys.stdout being buffered

start show2
hello
```

Note that the first routine will fail if you add `stdout=sys.stdout`, as a `StringIO` object has no `fileno`.  The second will omit the `hello` if you add `stdout=sys.stdout` since `sys.stdout` has been redirected to `os.devnull`.

(If you redirect Python's file-descriptor-1, the subprocess *will* follow that redirection.  The `open(os.devnull, 'w')` call produces a stream whose `fileno()` is greater than 2.)

Comment: Hmm.  Your demo seems to show the opposite of the claim in the end.  You're re-directing Python's stdout into the buffer but the subprocess stdout is still going to the console.  How is that useful?  Am I missing something?

Comment: @GuySirton: the demo shows that subprocess stdout (when not explicitly directed to `sys.stdout`) goes to *Python's* stdout, not the python *program*'s (`sys.`) stdout.  Which I admit is an ... odd distinction.  Is there a better way to phrase this?

Comment: that's good to know but we really want to capture the subprocess output here so changing sys.stdout is cool but doesn't help us I think.  Good observation that communicate must be using something like select(), poll or threads.

Comment: +1, good explanation but it lacks the concrete code examples. Here's [`asyncio`-based code that implements the "hard part" (it handles multiple pipes concurrently) in a portable way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25960956/4279). You could compare it to [the code that uses multiple threads (`teed_call()`) to do the same](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25755038/4279).

Comment: I've added an implementation with select()

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I'm trying the two-pipe Popen() but figuring out how to get both stdout and stderr 'live' results is making my head hurt.  Either one alone isn't a problem.

Comment: @ewong: Python3's subprocess is improved to the point where you often might not have to do anything fancy, but if you do have to do fancy tricks, it's still tricky.

Comment: @torek "on POSIX systems, at least, this does not mean it will use Python's sys.stdout, just Python's actual stdout". Do you know the reason for this behavior or where I can read more about it? I find this counter-intuitive and don't understand why it does not default to `sys.stdout` (or why `sys.stdout` is not "Python's actual stdout").

Comment: @SamirAguiar: I don't know of any good short summary, but it's pretty simple: at the POSIX OS level, "stdout" is simply "file descriptor #1". When you open a file, you get the *next available* fd, starting normally from 3 (because 0, 1, and 2 are stdin, stdout, stderr). If you then set up Python's `sys.stdout` to write to that—e.g., to fd 5 from your most recent `open` operation—and then fork and exec, the thing you exec is going to write to *its* fd#1. Unless you make special arrangements, their fd1 is your fd1, which is no longer your sys.stdout.

Comment: @SamirAguiar I think if you read the `sys` module's documentation it may help clarify it. I think the choice of names is unfortunate (confusing), but, e.g., `sys.stdout` is pretty much nothing more than "where the output of `print` will go." So, when you reassign it, you're not actually re-binding file descriptor 1 (which is what the subprocess sees). The `sys.__stdout__` is "Python's actual stdout."

Answer (score 30):

We can also use the default file iterator for reading stdout instead of using iter construct with `readline()`.

```py
import subprocess
import sys

process = subprocess.Popen(
    your_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
)
for line in process.stdout:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: The most elegant answer here!

Comment: This solution does not display in real time. It waits till the process is done and displays all the output at once. In Viktor Kerkez's solution, if "your_command" displays progressively, the output follows progressively, as long as "your_command" flushes stdout from time to time (because of the pipe).

Comment: @Nir because it's not live.

Comment: This solution iterates on the default descriptor, so it will only update when a line updates in the output. For a character based update you need to iterate on read() method as shown in Viktor's solution. But that was an overkill for my use case.

Comment: Quite real time, no need to wait for the process to exit. Thanks a lot

Comment: This solution does output in real time but only stdout.

Comment: My test for Python 3.11.0 on Mac shows that this solution correctly streams in real time. I don't understand why so many people say it's not. Maybe things are different in older version or different OS? Of course, since it reads line by line, the subprocess has to print line by line, too.

Answer (score 21):

In addition to all these answer, one simple approach could also be as follows:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(your_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while process.stdout.readable():
    line = process.stdout.readline()

    if not line:
        break

    print(line.strip())
```

Loop through the readable stream as long as it's readable and if it gets an empty result, stop.

The key here is that [`readline()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html) returns a line (with `\n` at the end) as long as there's an output and empty if it's really at the end.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Rather than `print(line.strip())`, probably better to `print(line, end="")` (default `end="\n"`) in case the line actually begins or ends with whitespace. And maybe `flush=True` as well, just in case those lines don't end in `"\n"`

Answer (score 12):

If you're able to use third-party libraries, You might be able to use something like [`sarge`](http://sarge.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html) (disclosure: I'm its maintainer). This library allows non-blocking access to output streams from subprocesses - it's layered over the `subprocess` module.

Comment: Fine work on sarge, BTW. That does indeed solve the OP's requirement, but might be a bit heavy handed for that use-case.

Comment: If you are suggesting a tool at least show an example of usage for this exact case.

Answer (score 11):

If all you need is that the output will be visible on the console the easiest solution for me was to pass the following arguments to `Popen`

```
with Popen(cmd, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr) as proc:
```

which will use your python scripts stdio file handles

Answer (score 7):

**Solution 1: Log `stdout` AND `stderr` concurrently in realtime**

A simple solution which logs both stdout AND stderr concurrently, line-by-line in *realtime* into a log file.

```py
import subprocess as sp
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def log_popen_pipe(p, stdfile):

    with open("mylog.txt", "w") as f:

        while p.poll() is None:
            f.write(stdfile.readline())
            f.flush()

        # Write the rest from the buffer
        f.write(stdfile.read())


with sp.Popen(["ls"], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, text=True) as p:

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as pool:
        r1 = pool.submit(log_popen_pipe, p, p.stdout)
        r2 = pool.submit(log_popen_pipe, p, p.stderr)
        r1.result()
        r2.result()
```

**Solution 2: A function `read_popen_pipes()` that allows you to iterate over both pipes (stdout/stderr), concurrently in realtime**

```py
import subprocess as sp
from queue import Queue, Empty
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def enqueue_output(file, queue):
    for line in iter(file.readline, ''):
        queue.put(line)
    file.close()


def read_popen_pipes(p):

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as pool:
        q_stdout, q_stderr = Queue(), Queue()

        pool.submit(enqueue_output, p.stdout, q_stdout)
        pool.submit(enqueue_output, p.stderr, q_stderr)

        while True:

            if p.poll() is not None and q_stdout.empty() and q_stderr.empty():
                break

            out_line = err_line = ''

            try:
                out_line = q_stdout.get_nowait()
                err_line = q_stderr.get_nowait()
            except Empty:
                pass

            yield (out_line, err_line)

# The function in use:

with sp.Popen(["ls"], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, text=True) as p:

    for out_line, err_line in read_popen_pipes(p):
        print(out_line, end='')
        print(err_line, end='')

    p.poll()
```

Comment: Thank you for "read_popen_pipes". It works like a charm and is easy to use even for a Python threading newbie like myself. Note for others: "return p.poll()" assumes the code is being run inside a function. To make it run as a standalone sample, just replace "return p.poll()" with "sys.exit(p.poll())" Also, replace "my_cmd" with ["ls"] or whatever command you want to run.

Comment: @DoomGoober Thanks for the kind words. I've fixed the code like you suggested. I left `sys.exit` out to keep the example as simple as possible.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to previous answers but the following solution worked for me on windows using Python3 to provide a common method to print and log in realtime ([source](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2015/01/28/getting-realtime-output-using-python))

```
def print_and_log(command, logFile):
    with open(logFile, 'wb') as f:
        command = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

        while True:
            output = command.stdout.readline()
            if not output and command.poll() is not None:
                f.close()
                break
            if output:
                f.write(output)
                print(str(output.strip(), 'utf-8'), flush=True)
        return command.poll()
```

Comment: If I also want to return the stdout in the end what would I modify?

Answer (score 3):

A good but "heavyweight" solution is to use Twisted - see the bottom.

If you're willing to live with only stdout something along those lines should work:

```
import subprocess
import sys
popenobj = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "-Rl"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while not popenobj.poll():
   stdoutdata = popenobj.stdout.readline()
   if stdoutdata:
      sys.stdout.write(stdoutdata)
   else:
      break
print "Return code", popenobj.returncode
```

(If you use read() it tries to read the entire "file" which isn't useful, what we really could use here is something that reads all the data that's in the pipe right now)

One might also try to approach this with threading, e.g.:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import threading

popenobj = subprocess.Popen("ls", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

def stdoutprocess(o):
   while True:
      stdoutdata = o.stdout.readline()
      if stdoutdata:
         sys.stdout.write(stdoutdata)
      else:
         break

t = threading.Thread(target=stdoutprocess, args=(popenobj,))
t.start()
popenobj.wait()
t.join()
print "Return code", popenobj.returncode
```

Now we could potentially add stderr as well by having two threads.

Note however the subprocess docs discourage using these files directly and recommends to use `communicate()` (mostly concerned with deadlocks which I think isn't an issue above) and the solutions are a little klunky so it really seems like **the subprocess module isn't quite up to the job** (also see: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3145/ ) and we need to look at something else.

A more involved solution is to use [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) as shown here: https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.1.0/core/howto/process.html

The way you do this with [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) is to create your process using `reactor.spawnprocess()` and providing a `ProcessProtocol` that then processes output asynchronously.  The Twisted sample Python code is here: https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.1.0/core/howto/listings/process/process.py

Comment: Thanks!  I just tried something like this (based on @PauloAlmeida 's comment, but my call to subprocess.Popen is blocking -- i.e. it only comes to the while loop once it returns...

Comment: That's not what's going on.  It's entering the while loop right away then blocking on the `read()` call until the subprocess exits and the parent process receives `EOF` on the pipe.

Comment: @Alp interesting!  so it is.

Comment: Yeah, I was too quick to post this.  It actually doesn't work properly and can't be easily fixed.  back to the drawing table.

Comment: @GuySirton haha, no problem - I appreciate the attempt!
It's strange - because the same thing was posted as a (well-received) 'answer' to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996887/how-to-replicate-tee-behavior-in-python-when-using-subprocess

Comment: @zhermes: So the problem with read() is that it will try to read the entire output till EOF which isn't useful.  readline() helps and may be all you need (really long lines can also be a problem though).  You also need to watch out for buffering in the process you're launching...

Answer (score 3):

Why not set `stdout` directly to `sys.stdout`? And if you need to output to a log as well, then you can simply override the write method of f.

```
import sys
import subprocess

class SuperFile(open.__class__):

    def write(self, data):
        sys.stdout.write(data)
        super(SuperFile, self).write(data)

f = SuperFile("log.txt","w+")       
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=f, stderr=f)
```

Comment: That wouldn't work: the subprocess module forks and sets the `stdout` file descriptor to the file descriptor of the passed file object. The write-method would never be called (at least that's what subprocess does for stderr, I gues it's the same for stdout).

Answer (score 3):

Based on all the above I suggest a slightly modified version (python3):

- while loop calling readline (The iter solution suggested seemed to block forever for me - Python 3, Windows 7)
- structered so handling of read data does not need to be duplicated after poll returns not-`None`
- stderr piped into stdout so both output outputs are read
- Added code to get exit value of cmd.

Code:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
while True:
    rd = proc.stdout.readline()
    print(rd, end='')  # and whatever you want to do...
    if not rd:  # EOF
        returncode = proc.poll()
        if returncode is not None:
            break
        time.sleep(0.1)  # cmd closed stdout, but not exited yet

# You may want to check on ReturnCode here
```

Answer (score 3):

None of the Pythonic solutions worked for me.
It turned out that `proc.stdout.read()` or similar may block forever.

Therefore, I use `tee` like this:

```py
subprocess.run('./my_long_running_binary 2>&1 | tee -a my_log_file.txt && exit ${PIPESTATUS}', shell=True, check=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

This solution is convenient if you are already using `shell=True`.

`${PIPESTATUS}` captures the success status of the entire command chain (only available in Bash).
If I omitted the `&& exit ${PIPESTATUS}`, then this would always return zero since `tee` never fails.

`unbuffer` might be necessary for printing each line immediately into the terminal, instead of waiting way too long until the "pipe buffer" gets filled.
However, unbuffer swallows the exit status of assert (SIG Abort)...

`2>&1` also logs stderror to the file.

Answer (score 3):

I found a simple solution to a much complicated problem.

1. Both stdout and stderr need to be streamed.
2. Both of them need to be non-blocking: when there is no output and when there are too much output.
3. Do not want to use Threading or multiprocessing, also not willing to use pexpect.

This solution uses a gist I found [here](https://gist.github.com/sebclaeys/1232088)

```py
import subprocess as sbp
import fcntl
import os

def non_block_read(output):
    fd = output.fileno()
    fl = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    try:
        return output.readline()
    except:
        return ""

with sbp.Popen('find / -name fdsfjdlsjf',
                shell=True,
                universal_newlines=True,
                encoding='utf-8',
                bufsize=1,
                stdout=sbp.PIPE,
                stderr=sbp.PIPE) as p:
    while True:
        out = non_block_read(p.stdout)
        err = non_block_read(p.stderr)
        if out:
            print(out, end='')
        if err:
            print('E: ' + err, end='')
        if p.poll() is not None:
            break
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like line-buffered output will work for you, in which case something like the following might suit. (Caveat: it's untested.)  This will only give the subprocess's stdout in real time.  If you want to have both stderr and stdout in real time, you'll have to do something more complex with `select`.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(run_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
while proc.poll() is None:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    print line
    log_file.write(line + '\n')
# Might still be data on stdout at this point.  Grab any
# remainder.
for line in proc.stdout.read().split('\n'):
    print line
    log_file.write(line + '\n')
# Do whatever you want with proc.stderr here...
```

Comment: Does not show live output. I get output first, if process is finished or terminated.

Answer (score 2):

All of the above solutions I tried failed either to separate stderr and stdout output, (multiple pipes) or blocked forever when the OS pipe buffer was full which happens when the command you are running outputs too fast (there is a warning for this on python poll() manual of subprocess). The only reliable way I found was through select, but this is a posix-only solution:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os
import select
# returns command exit status, stdout text, stderr text
# rtoutput: show realtime output while running
def run_script(cmd,rtoutput=0):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    poller = select.poll()
    poller.register(p.stdout, select.POLLIN)
    poller.register(p.stderr, select.POLLIN)

    coutput=''
    cerror=''
    fdhup={}
    fdhup[p.stdout.fileno()]=0
    fdhup[p.stderr.fileno()]=0
    while sum(fdhup.values()) < len(fdhup):
        try:
            r = poller.poll(1)
        except select.error, err:
            if err.args[0] != EINTR:
                raise
            r=[]
        for fd, flags in r:
            if flags & (select.POLLIN | select.POLLPRI):
                c = os.read(fd, 1024)
                if rtoutput:
                    sys.stdout.write(c)
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                if fd == p.stderr.fileno():
                    cerror+=c
                else:
                    coutput+=c
            else:
                fdhup[fd]=1
    return p.poll(), coutput.strip(), cerror.strip()
```

Comment: Another alternative is to spin off one thread per pipe. Each thread can do blocking I/O on the pipe, without blocking the other thread(s). But this introduces its own set of issues. All methods have annoyances, you just pick which one(s) you find least annoying. :-)

Comment: Does not work for me `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str`  -Python 3.8.5

Answer (score 2):

I think that the `subprocess.communicate` method is a bit misleading: it actually fills the *stdout* and *stderr* that you specify in the `subprocess.Popen`.

Yet, reading from the `subprocess.PIPE` that you can provide to the `subprocess.Popen`'s *stdout* and *stderr* parameters will eventually fill up OS pipe buffers and deadlock your app (especially if you've multiple processes/threads that must use `subprocess`).

My proposed solution is to provide the *stdout* and *stderr* with files - and read the files' content instead of reading from the deadlocking `PIPE`. These files can be `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` - which can also be accessed for reading while they're being written into by `subprocess.communicate`.

**Below is a sample usage:**

```py
try:
    with ProcessRunner(
        ("python", "task.py"), env=os.environ.copy(), seconds_to_wait=0.01
    ) as process_runner:
        for out in process_runner:
            print(out)
except ProcessError as e:
    print(e.error_message)
    raise
```

And this is the source code which is **ready to be used** with as many comments as I could provide to explain what it does:

If you're using python 2, please make sure to first install the latest version of the *subprocess32* package from pypi.

```py
import os
import sys
import threading
import time
import tempfile
import logging

if os.name == 'posix' and sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    # Support python 2
    import subprocess32 as subprocess
else:
    # Get latest and greatest from python 3
    import subprocess

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class ProcessError(Exception):
    """Base exception for errors related to running the process"""


class ProcessTimeout(ProcessError):
    """Error that will be raised when the process execution will exceed a timeout"""


class ProcessRunner(object):
    def __init__(self, args, env=None, timeout=None, bufsize=-1, seconds_to_wait=0.25, **kwargs):
        """
        Constructor facade to subprocess.Popen that receives parameters which are more specifically required for the
        Process Runner. This is a class that should be used as a context manager - and that provides an iterator
        for reading captured output from subprocess.communicate in near realtime.

        Example usage:


        try:
            with ProcessRunner(('python', task_file_path), env=os.environ.copy(), seconds_to_wait=0.01) as process_runner:
                for out in process_runner:
                    print(out)
        except ProcessError as e:
            print(e.error_message)
            raise

        :param args: same as subprocess.Popen
        :param env: same as subprocess.Popen
        :param timeout: same as subprocess.communicate
        :param bufsize: same as subprocess.Popen
        :param seconds_to_wait: time to wait between each readline from the temporary file
        :param kwargs: same as subprocess.Popen
        """
        self._seconds_to_wait = seconds_to_wait
        self._process_has_timed_out = False
        self._timeout = timeout
        self._process_done = False
        self._std_file_handle = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
        self._process = subprocess.Popen(args, env=env, bufsize=bufsize,
                                         stdout=self._std_file_handle, stderr=self._std_file_handle, **kwargs)
        self._thread = threading.Thread(target=self._run_process)
        self._thread.daemon = True

    def __enter__(self):
        self._thread.start()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self._thread.join()
        self._std_file_handle.close()

    def __iter__(self):
        # read all output from stdout file that subprocess.communicate fills
        with open(self._std_file_handle.name, 'r') as stdout:
            # while process is alive, keep reading data
            while not self._process_done:
                out = stdout.readline()
                out_without_trailing_whitespaces = out.rstrip()
                if out_without_trailing_whitespaces:
                    # yield stdout data without trailing \n
                    yield out_without_trailing_whitespaces
                else:
                    # if there is nothing to read, then please wait a tiny little bit
                    time.sleep(self._seconds_to_wait)

            # this is a hack: terraform seems to write to buffer after process has finished
            out = stdout.read()
            if out:
                yield out

        if self._process_has_timed_out:
            raise ProcessTimeout('Process has timed out')

        if self._process.returncode != 0:
            raise ProcessError('Process has failed')

    def _run_process(self):
        try:
            # Start gathering information (stdout and stderr) from the opened process
            self._process.communicate(timeout=self._timeout)
            # Graceful termination of the opened process
            self._process.terminate()
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
            self._process_has_timed_out = True
            # Force termination of the opened process
            self._process.kill()

        self._process_done = True

    @property
    def return_code(self):
        return self._process.returncode
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a class which I'm using in one of my projects. It redirects output of a subprocess to the log. At first I tried simply overwriting the write-method but that doesn't work as the subprocess will never call it (redirection happens on filedescriptor level). So I'm using my own pipe, similar to how it's done in the subprocess-module. This has the advantage of encapsulating all logging/printing logic in the adapter and you can simply pass instances of the logger to `Popen`: `subprocess.Popen("/path/to/binary", stderr = LogAdapter("foo"))`

```
class LogAdapter(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, logname, level = logging.INFO):
        super().__init__()
        self.log = logging.getLogger(logname)
        self.readpipe, self.writepipe = os.pipe()

        logFunctions = {
            logging.DEBUG: self.log.debug,
            logging.INFO: self.log.info,
            logging.WARN: self.log.warn,
            logging.ERROR: self.log.warn,
        }

        try:
            self.logFunction = logFunctions[level]
        except KeyError:
            self.logFunction = self.log.info

    def fileno(self):
        #when fileno is called this indicates the subprocess is about to fork => start thread
        self.start()
        return self.writepipe

    def finished(self):
       """If the write-filedescriptor is not closed this thread will
       prevent the whole program from exiting. You can use this method
       to clean up after the subprocess has terminated."""
       os.close(self.writepipe)

    def run(self):
        inputFile = os.fdopen(self.readpipe)

        while True:
            line = inputFile.readline()

            if len(line) == 0:
                #no new data was added
                break

            self.logFunction(line.strip())
```

If you don't need logging but simply want to use `print()` you can obviously remove large portions of the code and keep the class shorter. You could also expand it by an `__enter__` and `__exit__` method and call `finished` in `__exit__` so that you could easily use it as context.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

def execute(cmd, callback):
    for line in iter(os.popen(cmd).readline, ''): 
            callback(line[:-1])

execute('ls -a', print)
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and worked out a simple and clean solution using `process.sdtout.read1()` which works perfectly for my needs in python3.

Here is a demo using the `ping` command (requires internet connection):

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cmd = "ping 8.8.8.8"
proc = Popen([cmd], shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
while True:
    print(proc.stdout.read1())
```

Every second or so a new line is printed in the python console as the ping command reports its data in real time.

Answer (score 1):

I made a small correction towards [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57084403/12388699) by @Rotareti, and it works fine for process generating only stderr. The original answer used one try-catch block which blocked obtaining stderr outputs when stdout is empty. I also add support for timeout here.

```py
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/57084403
from typing import List, Tuple
import sys, io, queue
import subprocess
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


class Shell:
    def __init__(
        self,
        shell_exec: bool = True,
        print_out: bool = True,
        return_list: bool = False,
    ) -> None:
        self.shell_exec = shell_exec
        self.print_out = print_out
        self.return_list = return_list


    def _read_popen_pipes(self, p: subprocess.Popen, timeout_sec: float|None = None):

        def _enqueue_output(file: io.TextIOWrapper, q: queue.Queue):
            for line in iter(file.readline, ''):
                q.put(line)
            file.close()

        def _timeout():
            try:
                p.wait(timeout=timeout_sec)
            except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
                p.terminate()

        with ThreadPoolExecutor(3) as pool:
            q_stdout, q_stderr = queue.Queue(), queue.Queue()
            
            if timeout_sec is not None:
                pool.submit(_timeout)
            pool.submit(_enqueue_output, p.stdout, q_stdout)
            pool.submit(_enqueue_output, p.stderr, q_stderr)

            while p.poll() is None or not q_stdout.empty() or not q_stderr.empty():
                out_line = err_line = ''

                try:
                    out_line = q_stdout.get_nowait()
                except queue.Empty:
                    pass

                try:
                    err_line = q_stderr.get_nowait()
                except queue.Empty:
                    pass

                yield (out_line, err_line)


    def run(self, cmd: str | List[str], timeout: float|None = None) -> Tuple[str|List[str], str|List[str], int]:
        with subprocess.Popen(
            cmd, shell=self.shell_exec, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True,
        ) as p:
            out: List[str] = []
            err: List[str] = []
            for out_line, err_line in self._read_popen_pipes(p, timeout):
                out.append(out_line)
                err.append(err_line)
                if self.print_out:
                    print(out_line, end='', flush=True)
                    print(err_line, end='', file=sys.stderr, flush=True)
            # end for
            if self.return_list:
                return out, err, p.returncode
            else:
                return ''.join(out), ''.join(err), p.returncode


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Shell().run('''echo '#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..10}
do
    echo "Sleep $i to stdout" >> /dev/stdout
    echo "Sleep $i to stderr" >> /dev/stderr
    sleep 0.5
done
' > sleep.sh && chmod +x sleep.sh''')

    out, err, code = Shell().run('./sleep.sh', timeout=2)
    print(f'{out = }')
    print(f'{err = }')
    print(f'{code = }')

    Shell().run('rm sleep.sh')
```

Answer (score 0):

In my view "live output from subprocess command" means that both stdout and stderr should be live. And stdin should also be delivered to the subprocess.

The fragment below produces live output on stdout and stderr and also captures them as bytes in outcome.{stdout,stderr}.

The trick involves proper use of select and poll.

Works well for me on Python 3.9.

```
        if self.log == 1:
            print(f"** cmnd= {fullCmndStr}")

        self.outcome.stdcmnd = fullCmndStr
        try:
            process = subprocess.Popen(
                fullCmndStr,
                shell=True,
                encoding='utf8',
                executable="/bin/bash",
                stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            )
        except OSError:
            self.outcome.error = OSError
        else:
            process.stdin.write(stdin)
            process.stdin.close() # type: ignore

        stdoutStrFile = io.StringIO("")
        stderrStrFile = io.StringIO("")

        pollStdout = select.poll()
        pollStderr = select.poll()

        pollStdout.register(process.stdout, select.POLLIN)
        pollStderr.register(process.stderr, select.POLLIN)

        stdoutEOF = False
        stderrEOF = False

        while True:
            stdoutActivity = pollStdout.poll(0)
            if stdoutActivity:
                c= process.stdout.read(1)
                if c:
                    stdoutStrFile.write(c)
                    if self.log == 1:
                        sys.stdout.write(c)
                else:
                   stdoutEOF = True

            stderrActivity = pollStderr.poll(0)
            if stderrActivity:
                c= process.stderr.read(1)
                if c:
                    stderrStrFile.write(c)
                    if self.log == 1:
                        sys.stderr.write(c)
                else:
                   stderrEOF = True
            if stdoutEOF and stderrEOF:
                break

        if self.log == 1:
            print(f"** cmnd={fullCmndStr}")

        process.wait() # type: ignore

        self.outcome.stdout = stdoutStrFile.getvalue()
        self.outcome.stderr = stderrStrFile.getvalue()
        self.outcome.error = process.returncode # type: ignore
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way i've found how to read a subprocess' output in a streaming fashion (while also capturing it in a variable) in Python (for multiple output streams, i.e. both `stdout` and `stderr`) is by passing the subprocess a named temporary file to write to and then opening the same temporary file in a separate reading handle.

Note: this is for Python 3

```
    stdout_write = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    stdout_read = io.open(stdout_write.name, "r")
    stderr_write = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    stderr_read = io.open(stderr_write.name, "r")

    stdout_captured = ""
    stderr_captured = ""

    proc = subprocess.Popen(["command"], stdout=stdout_write, stderr=stderr_write)
    while True:
        proc_done: bool = cli_process.poll() is not None

        while True:
            content = stdout_read.read(1024)
            sys.stdout.write(content)
            stdout_captured += content
            if len(content) < 1024:
                break

        while True:
            content = stderr_read.read(1024)
            sys.stderr.write(content)
            stdout_captured += content
            if len(content) < 1024:
                break

        if proc_done:
            break

        time.sleep(0.1)

    stdout_write.close()
    stdout_read.close()
    stderr_write.close()
    stderr_read.close()
```

However, if you don't need to capture the output, then you can simply pass `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` streams from your Python script to the called subprocess, as xaav suggested [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42044754/532201) :

```
subprocess.Popen(["command"], stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but in **Python 3** -- tested in *Python 3.11* -- the following code worked for me, to stream live or "real time" output using the `subprocess` module:

```py
import sys
from os import fdopen
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT


with Popen(command,
           shell=True,
           stdout=PIPE,
           stderr=STDOUT) as sp:

    with fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'wb', closefd=False) as stdout:

        for line in sp.stdout:
            stdout.write(line)
            stdout.flush()
```

### Convenience Function

As it's idiomatic, I usually create a convenience function `run` to chain a list of commands in the terminal and stream the output in real time.

Note that I use `&&` as the separator here, but you could easily use another one, such as `;` if you don't want to fail early on error, or even `&` instead.

```py
import sys
from os import fdopen
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

def run(cmds, join='&&'):
    with Popen(join.join(cmds),
               shell=True,
               stdout=PIPE,
               stderr=STDOUT) as sp:
        with fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'wb', closefd=False) as stdout:
            for line in sp.stdout:
                stdout.write(line)
                stdout.flush()
```

Usage is like so:

```py
commands = [
    'echo hello',
    'sleep 3',
    'echo world',
    'sleep 2',
    'echo !',
]
run(commands)
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling the live output stream of a command can be achieved by iterating over `stdout` as the [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) runs.

This implementation:

- uses a with-statement such that standard file descriptors are closed, and the process is waited for
- propagates keyword arguments to the subprocess constructor
- defaults to `text=True` to automatically decode bytestrings into strings
- raises a `CalledProcessError` upon failure if `check=True` like [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) does
- returns a `CompletedProcess` upon success like [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) does
- uses two threads to handle stdout and stderr concurrently (for a version redirecting stdout to stderr without threads see my simplified [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76626021/5511061))

```py
import logging
from collections import deque
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial
from subprocess import PIPE, CalledProcessError, CompletedProcess, Popen


def stream_command(
    args,
    *,
    stdout_handler=logging.info,
    stderr_handler=logging.error,
    check=True,
    text=True,
    stdout=PIPE,
    stderr=PIPE,
    **kwargs,
):
    """Mimic subprocess.run, while processing the command output in real time."""
    with Popen(args, text=text, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr, **kwargs) as process:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as pool:  # two threads to handle the streams
            exhaust = partial(pool.submit, partial(deque, maxlen=0))
            exhaust(stdout_handler(line[:-1]) for line in process.stdout)
            exhaust(stderr_handler(line[:-1]) for line in process.stderr)
    retcode = process.poll()
    if check and retcode:
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args)
    return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode)
```

Logging to a file then becomes as simple as setting up [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig):

```py
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    filename="./capture.log",
    filemode="w",
    encoding="utf-8",
)
logging.info("test from python")
stream_command(["echo", "test from subprocess"])
```

With the resulting file:

```
$ cat ./capture.log
INFO:root:test from python
INFO:root:test from subprocess
```

The behaviour can be tweaked to preference (`print` instead of `logging.info`, or both, etc.):

```py
stream_command(["echo", "test"])
# INFO:root:test
stream_command("cat ./nonexist", shell=True, check=False)
# ERROR:root:cat: ./nonexist: No such file or directory
stream_command(["echo", "test"], stdout_handler=print)
# test
stdout_lines = []
def handler(line):
    print(line)
    logging.info(line)
    stdout_lines.append(line)
stream_command(["echo", "test"], stdout_handler=handler)
# test
# INFO:root:test
print(stdout_lines)
# ['test']
```

Answer (score 0):

None of them worked for me.
Python3.11 / Python3.12 Linux/Windows11

I get the stdout first, if the command is finished.
For Linux I found:

```
p=pexpect.spawn(cmd) / p.read_nonblocking()
```

But unfortunately, this doesn't work for Windows. I'm still searching for a solution for Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Works for me (Python 3.12):

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep

def run_shell(command):

    def printShellOut(process):
        out = process.stdout.readline()
        if out:
            print(out.decode(), flush = True, end='')
            return True
    
    def printShellErr(process):
        err = process.stderr.readline()
        if err:
            print('Error: ' + err.decode(), flush = True, end='')
            return True
    
    def printShell(process):
        while printShellOut(process):
            pass
        
        while printShellErr(process):
            pass
            
    
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    while process.poll() is None:
        printShell(process)
        sleep(0.5)
    
    printShell(process)
```

Comment: This question is over a decade old, and it has several answers. It's okay to answer old questions, but it's very hard to tell how this answer is different from the others that already exist. What did you do differently? Are you sure that this answer is different from _all_ other answers? How is this better than them? Why should we use this approach instead of the others?

Comment: @Chris
Try them out!
I've tried a few .... they are enterly not working, end up in an infinite loop, cause massive processor-load, store to a file and don't give a live-output in the console .... and don't include errors.

If there was one working I wouldn't had to search for hours to understand the subprocess-class and for sure wouldn't have posted my solution

Comment: You should include that in your answer. Otherwise this is just another code dump that nobody will look look at.

Comment: Does not show live output. I get output first, if process is finished or terminated.