# How to read live output from subprocess python 2.7 and Apache

Tags: apache, python-2.7, pipe, subprocess, ros

I have an Apache web server and I made a python script to run a command. Command that I'm running is launching a ROS launch file, that is working indefinitely. I would like to read output from the subprocess live and display it in the page. With my code so far I could only manage to make output to be printed after I terminate the process. I've tried all kinds of solutions from the web but none of them seem to work

```
command = "roslaunch package test.launch"
proc = subprocess.Popen(
   command,
   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
   stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
   env=env,
   shell=True,
   bufsize=1,
)
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
   strLine = str(line).rstrip()
   print(">>> " + strLine)
   print("<br/>")
```

Comment: have you tried to call `sys.stdout.flush()`?

Comment: There could be other buffers between your code and the screen. Have you tried obvious things such as, drop `subprocess` and just print with a pause: `print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n" for i in range(100): print ("%02d" % i) * 10000; time.sleep(1)` (perhaps you should use `Transfer-Encoding: chunk`)

Comment: ok tnx I will try, but what do you  mean by drop subprocess? How do I do that?

Comment: "drop subprocess" means that *for debugging* purposes, remove all subprocess-related code -- if you can't make simple print statements work then there is no point to complicate your example using `subprocess`. See [how to create a minimal complete code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I tried and it works but it prints all at once after 100 seconds, and not one by one...

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the output of `roslaunch` is being buffered. `subprocess` is not the best tool for real-time output processing in such situation, but there is a perfect tool for just that task in Python: `pexpect`. The following snippet should do the trick:

```
import pexpect

command = "roslaunch package test.launch"
p = pexpect.spawn(command)
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
while not p.eof():
    strLine = p.readline()
    print(">>> " + strLine)
    print("<br/>")
```

Answer (score 1):

Andrzej Pronobis' answer above suffices for UNIX-based systems but the package `pexpect` **does not work as effectively as one would expect for Windows** in certain particular scenarios. Here, spawn() doesn't work for Windows as expected. We still can use it with some alterations that can be seen [here](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#pexpect-on-windows) in the official docs.

The better way here might be to use `wexpect` (official docs [here](https://pypi.org/project/wexpect/)). **It caters to Windows alone**.