# Python - read output from long-running subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

Using the subprocess module (Python 2.7), I'm running a command and attempting to process its output as it runs.

I have code like the following:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(
    ['udevadm', 'monitor', '--subsystem=usb', '--property'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
    print(line)
```

However, the output only gets printed after I Ctrl+C, even if I add `sys.stdout.flush()` after the print statement.

Why is this happening, and how can I live stream the output from this process?

Notably, this `udevadm monitor` command is not intended to terminate, so I can't simply wait for the process to terminate and process its output all at once.

I found [live output from subprocess command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18422264/828709) but the approach in the accepted answer did not solve my problem.

Comment: see [the links in the paragraph that starts with: "If subprocess' stdout uses a block buffering"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [*unbuffer*](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer) :

```
process = subprocess.Popen(
    ["unbuffer", 'udevadm', 'monitor', '--subsystem=usb', '--property'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
    print(line)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. But is there a way to do this with only Python? I'd prefer to avoid the `expect` dependency.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot see a way but that certainly does not mean that there is not, I do see some output if I disconnect and reconnect something to the use port but in chunks more than line buffered and still a decent delay between output