# python-Can we use tempfile with subprocess to get non buffering live output in python app

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to run one python file from python windows application.For that I have used `subprocess`.For getting live streaming output on app console I have tried the below statements.

With PIPE

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)

for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    print line
```

(or)

```
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
while True:
    out = process.stdout.read(1)
    if out == '' and process.poll() != None:
        break
    if out != '':
        sys.stdout.write(out)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Not only above code ,tried so many methods.Getting same results like below:

**1.Python windows app taking so much of time to run**

**2.Then the app window went to "not responding" state for long time**

**3.Then whole output is printed on the console**

I know that the buffer overflow is happening in python app thats why i am not getting live output.

I posted so many queries for this still not getting solution.

Just now found and tried tempfile for this.But i am not sure this will give live streaming output.

Shall I try this way?

```
import tempfile
import subprocess

w = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=w, 
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, bufsize=0)

with open(w.name, 'r') as r:
    for line in r:
        print line
w.close()
```

Or any other best solutions for non blocking,unbuffering live output on windows app.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Note**:1.The python file which I want to run has more print statements(ie more content)

2.Windows server 2012,python 2.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand you're frustration. It looks like you've almost come to the answer yourself.

I'm building on the answer from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18422264/3991139). But that answer doesn't use `TemporaryFile` and also I used the tail follow method from [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/157035-tail-f-in-python/) which I have found to offer the fastest output to the terminal with very large volumes of output. This eliminates extraneous calls to `print`.

**Side note:** If you've got other asynchronous stuff to do then you can wrap up the code below the imports in a function and use the `gevent` package and import `sleep` from `gevent` and `Popen, STDOUT` from `gevent.subprocess`. It is what I'm doing and may help you avoid leftover slowdown (only reason I mention it).

```
import sys
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
from time import sleep
from subprocess import Popen, STDOUT

# the temp file will be automatically cleaned up using context manager
with TemporaryFile() as output:
    sub = Popen(cmd, stdout=output, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
    # sub.poll returns None until the subprocess ends,
    # it will then return the exit code, hopefully 0 ;)
    while sub.poll() is None:
        where = output.tell()
        lines = output.read()
        if not lines:
            # Adjust the sleep interval to your needs
            sleep(0.1)
            # make sure pointing to the last place we read
            output.seek(where)
        else:
            sys.__stdout__.write(lines)
            sys.__stdout__.flush()
    # A last write needed after subprocess ends
    sys.__stdout__.write(output.read())
    sys.__stdout__.flush()
```

Comment: I could not use `from __future__ import print_function`,since I have so many print in the current file.Is there any other possible way?

Comment: Yes, use sys.stdout.write instead of print, removing the end argument. I will edit the answer when I have time.

Comment: Okay, I changed the answer. I would try to use it without `sys.stdout.flush()` first and see if that works for you. I left it in for completeness.

Comment: With `sys.stdout.flush()` attribute error is coming. ` AttributeError: 'TextCtrl' object has no attribute 'flush' `.And no changes in the python app's behavior :-(

Comment: what if you remove the `sys.stdout.flush()` statements?

Comment: Your error indicates that your `sys.stdout` got reassigned at some point earlier in the program, as the original value for `sys.stdout` __should__ have a `flush` method. I've made an edit to the posted code which will use original value for stdout. Please try that.

Comment: It is printing on the windows command prompt(which runs in background for my python app),but not in my app console?....Usually to print anything in the app console i am using self.output.write().Here `self.output` is the `TextCtrl`

Comment: What framework/package are you using for your app console? This is very likely the root of the problem. If this is printing successfully to the command prompt then the code I provided is valid. At this point you need to better understand the data structure which controls the output to your "app console". Your original question did not provide details of a console separate from the standard command prompt. You may make edits to your original question or accept this answer and ask a new one detailing your framework as the source of the problem. I suggest the latter.

Comment: Ya this is working..I found the way to print in my app console with your code..Thanks.

Comment: But still I am facing the "Not responding" issue while running the file.

Comment: This fixed my hanging issue!  Because STDOUT buffers to memory, it can fill up after a few pages and cause your subprocess to hang!! Writing to a temp file fixes the issue.