# Terminal prompts for Jupyter Notebook for Python in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm having trouble running a batch file from a Jupyter Notebook in VScode. The prompts from the batch file are not showing up in the terminal when I run the script. Is there a way to print the prompts in the terminal instead of between cells? I've looked at a [similar problem on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616077/live-stdout-output-from-python-subprocess-in-jupyter-notebook), but it doesn't quite address my issue. I created a test file to open in a separate cmd window, but I would prefer to print it in the terminal instead. Here is the code I'm using:

Jupyter Notebook code:

```
subprocess.run("start test.bat", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, shell=True)
```

test.bat code:

```
@echo off
echo.
echo foo bar baz
```

Please see photo for clarification:
[image]

Comment: in what terminal do you want to print the bat file, in a new one or in one that already exists somewhere?

Comment: I figured it should be in the existing terminal in vscode

Comment: Please [edit] to put a more descriptive title. See [ask] for tips on that.

Answer (score 0):

The `start` command in codes `subprocess.run("start test.bat", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, shell=True)` opens a new command prompt window to run the specified program, which is why you're not seeing the output in your Jupyter notebook.

If you want the output to appear in your Jupyter notebook, you should run the batch file directly without using `start`.

```
result = subprocess.run("test.bat", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, shell=True)
print(result.stdout)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that I've been through this option already, but it's not the behaviour I'm looking for. Please see the picture I've uploaded in the original post.