# Running shell commands from Python and printing the output in real time

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I want to write a function that will execute multiple shell commands one at a time and print what the shell returns in real time.

I currently have the following code which does not print the shell (I am using Windows 10 and python 3.6.2):

```
commands = ["foo", "foofoo"]
p = subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe", shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, \
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
for command in commands:
    p.stdin.write((command + "\n").encode("utf-8"))
p.stdin.close()
p.stdout.read()
```

How can I see what the shell returns in real time ?

Edit : This question is not a duplicate of the two first links in the comments, they do not help printing **in real time**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [live output from subprocess command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421757/live-output-from-subprocess-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to handle `stdin` and `stdout` in different threads. That way one thread can be handling printing the output from `stdout` and another one writing new commands on `stdin`. However, since `stdin` and `stdout` are independent streams, I do not think this can guarantee the order between the streams. For the current example it seems to work as intended, though.

```
import subprocess
import threading

def stdout_printer(p):
    for line in p.stdout:
        print(line.rstrip())

commands = ["foo", "foofoo"]
p = subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                     universal_newlines=True)

t = threading.Thread(target=stdout_printer, args=(p,))
t.start()

for command in commands:
    p.stdin.write((command + "\n"))
    p.stdin.flush()

p.stdin.close()
t.join()
```

Also, note that I am writing `stdout` line by line, which is normally OK, since it tends to be buffered and being generated a line (or more) at a time. I guess it is possible to handle an unbuffered `stdout` stream (or e.g. `stderr`) character-by-character instead, if that is preferable.

Comment: This should also have a stderr_printer thread or else if the subprocess tries to do a blocking write to its stderr it can hang.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need something like this

```
commands = ["foo", "foofoo"]
p = subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe", shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, \
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
for command in commands:
    p.stdin.write((command + "\n").encode("utf-8"))
out, err = p.communicate()
print("{}".format(out))
print("{}".format(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want control of the output in your python code you might need to do something like this

```
import subprocess

def run_process(exe):
    'Define a function for running commands and capturing stdout line by line'
    p = subprocess.Popen(exe.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    commands = ["foo", "foofoo"]
    for command in commands:
        for line in run_process(command):
            print(line)
```