# continuous read from subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, hashcat

In Python, I have a question about the subprocess.Popen function, my problem is that I can't get my head around a continuous read of stdout stream. When I use `communicate()` at the end of my function, I get my preferred output. But I have two problems here. First, `communicate()` buffers the whole output before it prints anything and it would be nice to get an continuous output. Second, I had read in the `communicate()` documentation that `communicate()` isn't meant for big data streams which is in my scenario the case.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
from subprocess import *
import itertools


def combinate(hash_mode,hash_file,directory):
erg = Popen(['hashcat', '-a', '0', '-m', hash_mode, hash_file, '-O', '--potfile-disable'],
                     stdin=PIPE,
                     stdout=PIPE,
                     stderr=PIPE,
                     universal_newlines=True)
file = []
with os.scandir(directory) as listOfEntries:
    for entry in listOfEntries:
        if entry.is_file() and entry.name is not ".DS_Store":
            file.append(open(directory+entry.name).readlines())
    file = list(itertools.permutations(file))
    for b in range(0, len(file)):
        for i in itertools.product(*file[b]):
            test = '\n'.join(i).replace("\n", "")
            erg.stdin.writelines(test+'\n')

print(erg.communicate()[0])
```

This is my output with communicate:

```
Session..........: hashcat
Status...........: Cracked
Hash.Type........: SHA-512
Hash.Target......:          7ba4e9da57a7d3bd8b1b43c0b028a96d77721f6b33e3b85f0b2...298b56
Time.Started.....: Sat Feb 24 03:52:05 2018 (0 secs)
Time.Estimated...: Sat Feb 24 03:52:05 2018 (0 secs)
Guess.Base.......: Pipe
Speed.Dev.#2.....:   969.7 kH/s (0.13ms)
Recovered........: 1/1 (100.00%) Digests, 1/1 (100.00%) Salts
Progress.........: 384
Rejected.........: 0
Restore.Point....: 0
Candidates.#2....: telefon1telefon3telefon2 -> tasse2tasse3tasse1
```

And this is my output with an for loop with an stdout.readline:

```
Session..........: hashcat
Status...........: Running
Hash.Type........: SHA-512
Hash.Target......:  7ba4e9da57a7d3bd8b1b43c0b028a96d77721f6b33e3b85f0b2...298b56
Time.Started.....: Sat Feb 24 04:14:30 2018 (10 secs)
Time.Estimated...: Sat Feb 24 04:14:40 2018 (0 secs)
Guess.Base.......: Pipe
Speed.Dev.#2.....:        0 H/s (0.00ms)
Recovered........: 0/1 (0.00%) Digests, 0/1 (0.00%) Salts
Progress.........: 0
Rejected.........: 0
Restore.Point....: 0
Candidates.#2....: [Copying]
```

As you can see, I get an output, but the hashcat process doesn't get my stdin stream or doesn't process it and I don't know why.

How can I realize an continuous output with my code?

Comment: I think you need to post the `stdout.readline` code as `communicate` never can meet your requirements, it's useless to post this code here. BTW, if you could post a runnable code, that will be fine.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted to say with my long description. I already came to the conclusion that communicate() isn't right. And that's (more or less) runnable code, you just have to call combinate() and give the function parameter values for the 3 variables. The first two parameters are typical for hashcat, so if you know hashcat, you know what values the parameters need. And the third parameter just is a string path to a directory, where the function iterates over the found password dictionaries and combines them which each other. Sorry if there was something unclear ^^

Comment: You should consider using threads and have `stdout` and `stdin` run in separate threads, as e.g. in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48777349/7738328

Comment: WOW, you don't know how thankful I'm right now. The whole night I have tried many threading examples and yours is the first one which did exactly what I wanted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The answer from JohanL in the comments was my solution. Great thanks for that.

> You should consider using threads and have stdout and stdin run in separate threads, as e.g. in my answer here: [link of post][stackoverflow.com/a/48777349/7738328 – JohanL]