# Problems with python subprocess and stdout

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, freeze

Trying to make a python script that runs some bash jobs (for flashing) in separate threads using `subprocess.Popen`. While running I want to read the stdout of the processes so I can show some progress to the user in a simple curses interface. So each thread runs something like this:

```
def worker(panel):
    panel['status'] = 'STARTING'
    panel['process'] = Popen([SCRIPTFILE, panel['ip'], FWFILE, JADFILE, EXEFILE], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1048576)
    panel['status'] = 'RUNNING'

    line = " "
    while line:
        line = panel['process'].stdout.readline()
        panel['status'] = line
    panel['status'] = 'DONE'
```

I see in my UI that the status gets stuck on `STARTING` in this case, but looking at IP traffic it seems that it actually runs but never returns any output. So it seems as `Popen` actually runs the job but doesn't return. And as soon as the other processes finish it seems it stops hanging and I get all the data at once as it was buffered. I have seen warnings about reading from stdout on a subprocess, but those warnings seem to be related to other scenarios. And I can't really use `communicate()` instead as it waits for the process to finish. Any idea what could make `Popen` hang like this?

Tried to make a minimal version showing the problem here (running with python 2.7 on Linux (change find path in script if windows)):

```
import curses
import time
from subprocess import *
import threading

def check_done(panels):
    done = True

    for panel in panels:
        if panel['status'] != 'DONE':
            done = False
            break

    return done

def flash_worker(panel):
    panel['status'] = 'STARTING'

    panel['process'] = Popen(["find", "/usr"], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1048576)

    panel['status'] = 'RUNNING'

    line = " "

    while line:
        line = panel['process'].stdout.readline()

        panel['status'] = line

    panel['status'] = 'DONE'

def ui_worker(panels):
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()
    stdscr.keypad(1)
    stdscr.scrollok(1)

    stdscr.erase()
    stdscr.refresh()

    while not check_done(panels):
        y = 0

        stdscr.clear()

        stdscr.addstr(y, 0, "IP")
        stdscr.addstr(y, 15, "Status")

        height, width = stdscr.getmaxyx()

        for i in range(0, len(panels)):
            y = y + 1
            stdscr.addstr(y, 0, "%s" % (panels[i]['ip']))
            stdscr.addstr(y, 15, "%s" % (panels[i]['status']))

        stdscr.refresh()
        time.sleep(0.1)

    curses.nocbreak();
    stdscr.keypad(0);
    curses.echo()
    curses.endwin()

def main():
    panels = []

    for i in range(0,25):
        panels.append({ 'ip' : '192.168.0.%d' % (i), 'mac' : '', 'status' : '', 'thread' : None, 'success' : False })

    for panel in panels:
        panel['thread'] = threading.Thread(name='Panel %s' % (panel['ip']), target = flash_worker, args = (panel,))
        panel['thread'].start()

    try:
        ui_worker(panels)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Caught KeyboardInterrupt, terminating..."

    for panel in panels:
        panel['thread'].join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [live output from subprocess command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421757/live-output-from-subprocess-command)

Comment: Not sure it's the same problem, but I will try the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, not a 100% sure why it works. But setting **close_fds=True** when forking (with Popen) solves the problem.