# Reading command line output from ongoing processes in terminal

Tags: python, command-line, output

I have used subprocess to obtain the output from command line, but it requires the process to end before you can use the data. Is there a way to get data line by line as it outputs? I need to have a process running indefinitely while python gets each new line as it is printed out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [live output from subprocess command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421757/live-output-from-subprocess-command)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the Process ID or PID, You can do `subprocess.call('tail -f /proc/<pid>/fd/1')`