# Python subprocess readline is blocking even after closing stdout

Tags: python, subprocess

test.py file

```
#test.py

#!/usr/bin/env python3

while True:
    inp = input("input: ")
    print("output: " + inp)
```

subp.py file:

```
#subp.py

#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cmd = Popen(["python3", "test.py"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)

while True:
    print("Writing to stdin")
    cmd.stdin.write("My Input To PIPE")
    print("Done Writing to stdin")
    print("Reading from stdout")
    s = cmd.stdout.readline()
    print("Done reading from stdout") # Never executes this line
```

The output is the following:

```
Writing to stdin

Done Writing to stdin

Reading from stdout
```

I understand that the line `s = cmd.stdout.readline()` is going to block until `EOF` is found in the `stdout` file object.

And if I am right, `EOF` will never be found in `stdout` unless `stdout` gets closed ? Can somebody correct me on this?

Going by my understanding, if I modify `test.py`

`import sys`

```
while True:
    inp = input("input: ")
    print("output: " + inp)
    sys.stdout.close() # Added this line hoping to unblock stdout.readline()
```

Nothing changes, `cmd.stdout.readline()` still is looking for `EOF` even though the `stdout file` is closed ?

What am I missing? I am more concerned about the theory rather done just making it work without understanding. Thank you for the explanations

Also if modify `subp.py` and add the line `cmd.stdout.close()` before the line `s = cmd.stdout.readline()`, it throws an error saying that I tried reading from a closed file object, which makes sense, but how come it did not throw an error when I close the `stdout` file object in the `test.py` file by adding the line `sys.stdout.close()`. Are these two stdout different things?

Comment: You need `cmd.stdin.close()` after you are done writing. Note, however, that writing to the cmd's stdin without simultaneously reading from its stdout (and stderr if that is piped, though it's not here) risks deadlock. For this reason, the subprocess routines can do the stdin-writing for you.

Comment: Can  you explain the theory why deadlock would occur? If I write to stdin, then `test.py` will see that and simply output to stdout? So I can do `cmd.stdout.read()`. Why would there be a possibility of deadlock? Also why do i have to do `cmd.stdin.close()` ?

Comment: Also if your files actually look like that, your `#!` lines aren't doing anything. Those only do anything at the start of a file. It looks like you're actually running your `subp.py` on Python 2, judging by the str/bytes handling.

Comment: The `cmd.stdin.close()` call closes the pipe feeding out from the main process to the subprocess's stdin, so that the subprocess sees EOF. You already said that you need that; that's what this does. (What you are/were missing is that the *child*'s stdout is not the *parent*'s stdout.) As to the deadlock, however, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18423003/1256452) to https://stackoverflow.com/q/18421757/1256452. This is a bit outdated now (python3 has a fancier way to do it) but the core concepts still apply.

Comment: Hi, I read your answer and it gave me a lot of insights and understanding; I also read about how pipes work & i feel very solid about the theory. So now the, how can I change my `subp.py` file so that I can get real time updates from the `while True` loop? Again, the `cmd.stdout.readline()` will get stuck looking for an EOF which it will never find because `test.py` is an infinite loop & the program will never end  to close the stdout ( giving EOF ). I can't use `output, err = cmd.communicate(input='blah')` either because it only supplies me the first output.