# python read dynamic stdout process

Tags: python, stdout

i try to read dynamic airodump-ng stdout with python, example process output -> https://i.makeagif.com/media/8-22-2015/EgkrBx.gif

i'm already to get output as text file, but the result is not in real time, so i try to directly read the stdout

```
import subporcess
subprocess.getoutput("timeout 10 airodump-ng args")
```

expected result :

run command and get real time output of called process `stdout`

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421757/live-output-from-subprocess-command  This is a stream and needs to be iterated over.

Comment: @JasonBaumgartner that not like what i expected