# From a Python script, run all Python scripts in a directory and stream output

Tags: python

My file structure looks like this:

```
runner.py
scripts/
    something_a/
        main.py
        other_file.py
    something_b/
        main.py
        anythingelse.py
    something_c/
        main.py
    ...
```

`runner.py` should look at all folders in `scripts/` in run the `main.py` located there.

Right now I'm achieving this through `subprocess.check_output`. It works, but some of these scripts take a long time to run and I don't get to see any progress; it prints everything after the process has finished.

I'm hoping to find a solution that allows for 2 things to be done somewhat easily:

> 1) Stream the output instead of getting it all at the end
>
> 2) Doesn't
>   prohibit running multiple scripts at once

Is this possible? A lot of the solutions I've seen for running a Python script from another require knowledge of the other script's name/location. I *can* also enforce that all the `main.py`'s have a specific function if that helps.

Comment: I would either look at using the threading library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)  so that you can run multiple scripts at the same time and if one of them hangs it doesn't impact the rest; or if that doesn't suit use a timeout on your subprocess call to stop the job after a certain time. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.alarm

Comment: Did you try https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate? Do you need *stdout* and / or *stderr*? Also, could you please add what you have so far?

Comment: The main issue with subprocess isn't that it takes too long or that I can't parallelize it. It's just that I want to stream the process which doesn't seem to be easily supported with subprocess.

Comment: Have a look here for how to stream the output with subprocess: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421757/live-output-from-subprocess-command

Answer (score 2):

You could use Popen to loop through each file and write its content to multiple log files. Then, you could read from these files in real-time, while each one is populated. :)

How you would want to translate the output to a more readable format, is a little bit more tricky because of readability. You could create another script which reads these log files, with Popen, and decide on how you'd like this information read back in a understandable manner.

```
""" Use the same command as you would do for check_output """
cmd = ''

for filename in scriptList:
   log = filename + ".log"
   with io.open(filename, mode=log) as out:
        subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=out, stderr=out)
```