# tqdm: simple loop on iterations, show MB/s

Tags: python, progress-bar, tqdm

### Question

I want to do a simple loop over `n` iterations. Each iteration contains a copy operation of which I know how many bytes were copied. My question is: how can I also show the number of MB/s in the progress bar?

### Example

I'm showing a progress bar around `rsync`. I modified [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18422264) as follows:

```py
import subprocess
import sys
import re
import tqdm

n = len(open('myfiles.txt').readlines())
your_command = 'rsync -aP --files-from="myfiles.txt" myhost:mysource .'
pbar = tqdm.trange(n)

process = subprocess.Popen(your_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
    line = line.decode("utf-8")
    if re.match(r'(.*)(xfr\#)([0-9])(.*)(to\-chk\=)([0-9])(.*)', line):
        pbar.update()
```

Whereby `myfiles.txt` contains a list of files. This gives me a good progress bar, showing the number of iterations per second.

However, the summary line that I match on to signal that a file was copied, e.g.

```
  682,356 100%  496.92kB/s    0:00:01 (xfr#5, to-chk=16756/22445)
```

also contains the number of bytes that were copied, which I want to use to show a copying speed.

Comment: Updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66169844/941531) to correctly do progress without jumping and without floating points arithmetics at all, just through using `unit_scale = True`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below I provided code doing what you need.

Because I didn't have your example data I created simple generator function that emulates process of retrieving data. It generates at random points of time (on each iteration) value equal to random number of bytes (not mega-bytes).

There are two `tqdm` bars below, one is used for progress, it measures iterations per second and total number of iterations done and percentage. And second bar that measures speed in megabytes per second and total number of megabytes received.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow66169469#main.py)

```
import tqdm
def gen(cnt):
    import time, random
    for i in range(cnt):
        time.sleep(random.random() * 0.125)
        yield random.randrange(1 << 20)
total_iterations = 150
pbar = tqdm.tqdm(total = total_iterations, ascii = True)
sbar = tqdm.tqdm(unit = 'B', ascii = True, unit_scale = True)
for e in gen(total_iterations):
    pbar.update()
    sbar.update(e)
```

Output:

```
  9%|█████████▉                               | 89/1000 [00:11<01:53,  8.05it/s]
40.196MiB [00:11,  3.63MiB/s]
```

ASCII video (+[link](https://asciinema.org/a/390800)):

[image: gif]

Comment: Thanks for this great answer! I do have two questions: is there a way to avoid the cursor to jump around (as you see in you movie as well)? Is there a way to format the total number MBs, e.g. `{.2f}`?

Comment: @TomdeGeus One obvious way to avoid jumping is to feed to .update() not floating megabytes, but integer kilobytes. Then you will see nice integer 16384 KB instead of 15.99999999 Megabytes. I'll put a look into doc to see if floating formatting is possible.

Comment: @TomdeGeus Just found out how to do it correctly without jumping! See my updated code. Now I just feed integer bytes instead of floating megabytes, also set unit to `'B'` bytes, and put `unit_scale = True`, this way `tqdm` scales to MegaBytes by itself instead of me doing it manually through floating point arithmetics. Video above I did NOT updated to reflect this change, because it is a lot of manual work to create such video. Just updated code.

Comment: Amazing. It'd upvote twice if I would have the capability!

Comment: @TomdeGeus Decided to also update my video (updated) :)