# how to get remote infomation (like the data of progress loading) using python

Tags: python, git, github

For example, I pull a file from Repo, and it will give me some information in Git, I wanna take this data using Python and make some data visualization

For instance, I want to collect the below data:-

[image: 1]

Comment: I guess you could force git to show its progress through using `--progress` (because if it's not connected to a tty, git will probably skip progress) and analyze the output of the `subprocess` call. And welcome to SO!

Comment: have u any example pleasesssssss.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421757/live-output-from-subprocess-command Keep in mind that in order to read progress, you must avoid reading by lines because progress does not write lines. It writes `\r` (if I recall correctly) when it will write a new progress update. Then when a progress line is done (a process in completed) it will write `\n`. Well.... that is if you want to show live progress. If all you care about is the final state, then you can read lines.