# How to get live output with subprocess in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I am trying to run a python file that prints something, waits 2 seconds, and then prints again. I want to catch these outputs live from my python script to then process them. I tried different things but nothing worked.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    output = process.stdout.readline()
    if process.poll() is not None and output == '':
        break
    if output:
        print(output.strip())
```

I'm at this point but it doesn't work. It waits until the code finishes and then prints all the outputs.

I just need to run a python file and get live outputs from it, if you have other ideas for doing it, without using the print function let me know, just know that I have to run the file separately. I just thought of the easiest way possible but, from what I'm seeing it can't be done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [live output from subprocess command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421757/live-output-from-subprocess-command)

Comment: i already tried every there, it doesn't work

Comment: There are three layers of buffering here, and you need to limit all three of them to get live data: 1) Use `stdbuf` or alter the program itself to change the buffering of the program to line-oriented mode (or add `fflush`s); without that, everything is stuck in the subprocess's user-mode buffers. 2) Add `bufsize=1` to the `Popen` arguments (probably not needed since you don't send `stdin`, but harmless). 3) Add `flush=True` to the `print` arguments (if you're connected to a terminal, the line-buffering will flush it for you, so it's only if stdout is piped to a file that this will matter).

Comment: To be clear, `stdbuf` in #1 is the *NIX-world solution; you'd just change the `Popen` to run `['stdbuf', '-oL'] + cmd`.

Comment: Thank you @ShadowRanger, the problem was the flush=True on the print.

Comment: @yonislacorte: Huh, was not expecting that to be the issue; were you piping to a file and refreshing the file or something? Since your `print` didn't suppress the newline with `end=''` or the like (and you stripped the newline from what you were `print`ing), I'd expect the default line-buffering to `stdout` to have been doing an implicit `flush` for you. Weird. I'll convert to an answer regardless.

Comment: yes, I wasn't expecting that too, I thought it was implicit, but it wasn't

Comment: @yonislacorte: Well, it should be implicit under normal circumstances; Python uses roughly the same rules as the C runtime, so, assuming you didn't pass any flags or set any environment variables that would unbuffer it, `sys.stdout` is line-buffered when `isatty` returns true, and block-buffered otherwise. At a guess, you might be running in an IDE environment that simulates a terminal poorly (e.g. connecting Python's `stdout` to a pipe which it reads to fill in its pseudoterminal; IDLE does this, and it ships with Python; it's common), leaving `stdout` block-buffered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three layers of buffering here, and you need to limit all three of them to guarantee you get live data:

1. Use the `stdbuf` command (on Linux) to wrap the `subprocess` execution (e.g. run `['stdbuf', '-oL'] + cmd` instead of just `cmd`), or (if you have the ability to do so) alter the program itself to either explicitly change the buffering on `stdout` (e.g. using `setvbuf` for C/C++ code to switch `stdout` globally to line-buffered mode, rather than the default block buffering it uses when outputting to a non-tty) or to insert flush statements after critical output (e.g. `fflush(stdout);` for C/C++, `fileobj.flush()` for Python, etc.) the buffering of the program to line-oriented mode (or add fflushs); without that, everything is stuck in user-mode buffers of the sub-process.
2. Add `bufsize=0` to the `Popen` arguments (probably not needed since you don't send anything to stdin, but harmless) so it unbuffers all piped handles. If the `Popen` is in `text=True` mode, switch to `bufsize=1` (which is line-buffered, rather than unbuffered).
3. Add `flush=True` to the `print` arguments (if you're connected to a terminal, the line-buffering will flush it for you, so it's only if stdout is piped to a file that this will matter), or explicitly call `sys.stdout.flush()`.

Between the three of these, you should be able to guarantee no data is stuck waiting in user-mode buffers; if at least one line has been output by the sub-process, it will reach you immediately, and any output triggered by it will also appear immediately. Item #1 is the hardest in most cases (when you can't use `stdbuf`, or the process reconfigures its own buffering internally and undoes the effect of `stdbuf`, and you can't modify the process executable to fix it); you have complete control over #2 and #3, but #1 may be outside your control.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use for that same purpose:

```py
def run_command(command, **kwargs):
    """Run a command while printing the live output"""
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        command,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        **kwargs,
    )
    while True:   # Could be more pythonic with := in Python3.8+
        line = process.stdout.readline()
        if not line and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        print(line.decode(), end='')
```

An example of usage would be:

```py
run_command(['git', 'status'], cwd=Path(__file__).parent.absolute())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat stdout and stderr separately, you can spawn two threads that handle them concurrently (live as the output is produced).

Adapted from my more detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76634163/5511061):

```py
import logging
from collections import deque
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial
from subprocess import PIPE, CalledProcessError, CompletedProcess, Popen


def stream_command(
    args,
    *,
    stdout_handler=logging.info,
    stderr_handler=logging.error,
    check=True,
    text=True,
    stdout=PIPE,
    stderr=PIPE,
    **kwargs,
):
    """Mimic subprocess.run, while processing the command output in real time."""
    with Popen(args, text=text, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr, **kwargs) as process:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as pool:  # two threads to handle the streams
            exhaust = partial(pool.submit, partial(deque, maxlen=0))
            exhaust(stdout_handler(line[:-1]) for line in process.stdout)
            exhaust(stderr_handler(line[:-1]) for line in process.stderr)
    retcode = process.poll()
    if check and retcode:
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args)
    return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode)
```

Call with simple `print` handlers:

```py
stream_command(["echo", "test"], stdout_handler=print, stderr_handler=print)
# test
```

Or with custom handlers:

```py
outs, errs = [], []
def stdout_handler(line):
    outs.append(line)
    print(line)
def stderr_handler(line):
    errs.append(line)
    print(line)

stream_command(
    ["echo", "test"],
    stdout_handler=stdout_handler,
    stderr_handler=stderr_handler,
)
# test
print(outs)
# ['test']
```