# how to read shadow file in linux using python script

Tags: file-io

file = open('/etc/shadow', 'r')
print(file)

getting error like this 
   file = open('/etc/shadow', 'r')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/shadow'

Answer (score 1):

On most systems /etc/shadow is owned by root with rw permissions.

```
$ ls -la /etc/shadow
```

-rw------- 1 root root 692 Jun 10 19:24 /etc/shadow
You need to either:

1. Change the permissons (don't do this it is not safe)
   but you could this by running 'chmod o+r /etc/shadow' as root. This will give the 'other' users read rights to
2. Run  your program as root. Either by 
   a. Starting it as  root
   `su -c 'python myPython.py'` //you will be asked to provide the root password.

   b. Starting it with sudo [1]
   `sudo python myPython.py` this all depends on you sudo configuration but is your best bet other then just starting python as root.

Also an example to call sudo from within python[5].

c. Set setuid bit on the program [2]
    This will most likely not work as Python is an interpreted language and most modern Unix systems will disallow (exception being Perl) setuid on interpreted programs as opposed to compiled/binaries.

`chown root programName   # Set owner to be root`

`chmod +s programName     # This gives the program itself the right to run as root.`

Regardless of whom starts it.

[1]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo

[2]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid

[3][Open a file as superuser in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354834/open-a-file-as-superuser-in-python)

[4][Setuid bit on python script : Linux vs Solaris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314012/setuid-bit-on-python-script-linux-vs-solaris)

[5][Using sudo with Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045593/using-sudo-with-python-script)

The problem is not with the source code or python. But with not having the correct file system rights to the '/etc/shadow' file.

Answer (score 1):

In python 3 you can do:

```
import spwd
spwd.getspnam('username')
```

More information about the `spwd` module can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/spwd.html#module-spwd